# Detect pushing navigator

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a view (Template). I access params with "appNavigator.getCurrentPage();". Since OnsenUI 1.3.11 finally fixed the flickering problem with child navigator inside of a tab-bar, I've added an "insideTabNavigator". (So I can keep the tab-bar)

The Problem is, that both the appNavigator and the insideTabNavigator can make a pushPage to that specific template with parameters. How can I determine which navigator did the push?

(inside of that specific controller)

I tried

```
if(typeof insideNavigator !== "undefined") {
    page = insideNavigator.getCurrentPage();
} else {
    page = appNavigator.getCurrentPage();
}
```

This will only work once. As soon as the insideNavigator var exist, it will always be true. I need to know which navigator initiated the push to access the correct one.

Is there any official way? I know, I could save a $rootScope var on prePush but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: what if you also pass a placeholder parameter when you push the page,?for example `0` if it's the `appNavigator` and `1` if it's the `insideTabNavigator `?

Comment: @Andi Pavllo that wouldn't be possible and I'm already doing this with a rootscope variable which I set on pre push, but it's not that nice. Ons-back-button directive also knows which navigator pushed. Some months before there was a ons.navigator which always returned the global active navigator. I think onsen should return somehow the active one. Is this possible? By the way, I did it with a rootscope var cause your suggestion would not work as I also need to access the navigator first before I could determine which one has the specific parameter inside

Comment: @Hirbod There is a `navigator` object in `prepush` and `postpush` events that points to the actual navigator that made the push. This object is also available in page objects like this: `myNav.getCurrentPage().navigator`. Of course I guess you don't know `myNav`, but in case you can save the current page somewhere after pushing you could access to its navigator afterwards. I hope you find something of this useful!

Comment: @FranDios thank you, this is a good idea.